# Computing ECC public key from a private key in JavaCard

Tags: smartcard, javacard, elliptic-curve

With Java Card APIs, which "support" Elliptic curves, how do I compute a public key given a known secret key.

Following a DH shared secret negotiation I'm interested in deriving common shared keys.  According to TR-03111 and X9.63 the shared secret from the DH ECC key agreement should not be used but, according to my understanding, the affine representation of the x-coordinate (The x component of the public key associated with the shared secret as a private key) is to be used.

With BigInteger arithmetic or ECPoint.multiply() this easy, but no such APIs exist in Java Card.

Comment: Do you use KeyAgreement class? Why don't you just call generateSecret?

Comment: I've used the KeyAgreement class to generate a shared secret.  Now I want to use the shared secret as a private key and derive the public key.  As far as I can tell KeyAgreement can't be used for this.

Comment: [Stefan](https://stackoverflow.com/users/15635852) posted an [Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67093291) saying "You may want to try [JCMathLib](https://github.com/OpenCryptoProject/JCMathLib) introduced in [Towards Low-level CryptographicPrimitives for JavaCards](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1810.01662.pdf)if you depend on javacard < 3.1.0"

Answer (score 1):

This multiplication isn't directly available for Java Card. Basically Java Card hides low level operations for you.

However, if you have a relatively new Java Card you may get away with this by using a `KeyAgreement` instance created using `ALG_EC_SVDP_DH_PLAIN_XY`. What you can do is to create a `ECPublicKey` where the public key point is simply set to point G. This base point G is part of the domain parameters. The private key should of course be set to your value.

Then all it comes down to is to perform a key agreement; the result of the agreement will be the points X and Y of the public key.

---

Note that support of any algorithm constant depends on the card implementation. The constant will be there - if the implemented API is new enough - but the algorithm may not be implemented.